# How can I make this post into a proper Q&A?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, etiquette, self-answer

I am the owner of a post, which I wrote, because I found not a single wiki or how-to or tutorial on the Internet about that subject.

Here is the post/question: *[How to build Qt for Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5601950/how-to-build-qt-for-visual-studio-2010)*

But, I'm still a beginner in the Stack Overflow world and I don't understand what is the proper way to write something when I want to share some *information*. In a wiki it would be obvious; I would just open a new page. But what would you do in this case? I thought I should just put the *information* in a question, as everyone would just read that. But I was wrong, as it got closed.

Do I understand it right that I should make it into a question, and answer it *myself*? And later? Shall I leave that question open forever?

Comment: Eh, may not be around, so I'm unlocking and reopening.  Please do follow through with your edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I understand it right, that I should make it into a question, and answer it myself?

Yes.

> And later? Shall I leave that question open forever?

Yes. Bad questions are closed. Good questions remain open. However, you can and should accept your own answer (requires waiting 48 hours after the question is posted).

Comment: But should I accept it after 48 hours? I mean what is better for the **life of the thread**, if its closed of if its open?

Comment: @zsero Yes, you should accept your answer.

Comment: OK, I understand now, I was confused between open-closed and accepted-unaccepted.

Comment: And, @zsero, *if* a better answer comes in some time later (not likely in this case!), you can always move the "accept" from your answer to that better one. (These Q&A sites are not forums in which a problem "is solved" and then gets "closed".) You can accept 48 hours *after asking*, so you can actually accept right away to indicate that for you the question is answered though.

Answer (score 3):

Don't post the solution in the question itself, there's no point in doing that. Here's why:

- first of all, if you leave the question separate from the answer, it will allow others to post their own answers, without having to edit your own post. This allows for multiple solutions to any given problem, without artificially promoting a single answer.
- it leaves things uncluttered, organized.
- for another thing, it will separate the votes the question and the answers receive. The question might be good, but the solution might be bad; what exactly do I vote?
- don't forget, this is the way Stack Overflow works: questions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to separate the question and the answer. In your case, all you need to do to achieve that is to leave only the question part (the title and the first paragraph) and to move everything else to the answer.

Hit *Answer your own question* at the bottom of the page and just move all that text over there. Then, it is a real question with a real answer.

BTW, thanks for the post!